# Lookbehind regex not working in firefox/safari

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox, safari

I use js library when is regular expression: /((?<!@).)/

But it doesnt work in safari/firefox.
Does anyone have an idea what equivalent can work in Safari? (Without lookbehind)

Comment: If the solutions from the linked post do not work, please explain that in the question.